# Instagram API - Redirect url

Tags: api, instagram

I have a plugin that need some instagram infos of my application.
This plugin just show photo feed.

I have created the application on the instagram developers and get my client id, but, what's the redirect url? I put my website link because i really don't understand what is that.

What i need is:

```
id: 'MY PROFILE ID',
redirectUrl: 'http://www.kyriosfestival.com.br',
clientId: 'MY CLIENT ID FROM MY APPLICATION',
accessToken: 'GENERATED FROM INTERNET'
```

And it's not working.
I have used a access token generated from internet, and i don't know if is this the problem.

What is the real form to use that?

Anyone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Must be late, but will post an answer, so that maybe it will help anyone some day.

For all your Instagram API calls, you need to receive a valid access token.

You can get one by implementing authentication (client-side or server-side), full guide can be found [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

So for example, if you choose to go with client-side authentication,
you should direct a user to authentication URL, which will looks like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

After that, user will be redirected to your redirect page (REDIRECT-URI). This REDIRECT-URI should match the URL you have specified in Manage Clients section.

After the redirect happens, you will get the access token in the URL of the page you've been redirected to.

```
http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

You can then extract your ACCESS-TOKEN from url and start making API calls.

Comment: What if I am want to use API on Product pages? Like every product page has a different and dynamic URL, am I supposed to add every link to ManageClient section?

Comment: Why does it response back with `#` rather than `?`, I can't extract `$_GET` with PHP if it isn't a `?`.