# Get JSON from website (instagram)

Tags: javascript, python, json

I recently got the idea to scrape information from instagram accounts and their posts, like the amount of comments or amount of likes. I got so far that I figured out while debugging in chrome that for example the link **https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a** under the network tab returns a JSON with the wanted information, but what is actually loaded is still the normal website html code.

[image: json data]

so far I tried in python with this code:

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(r.read())
```

or in javascript :

```
window.onload = function () {
    res = fetch("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a", {
        method: 'get'
    }).then(function (data) {
        return data.json();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR".concat(error.toString()));
    });
    console.log(res.user);
};
```

So the problem I have, is that when using these functions I only get the website code (**html**), is there a way to only get the JSON which is loaded in the background? I know people will recommend me using the instagram api, but I have no website nor a company to register.

Comment: url also have query_hash -- you don't have that. It might also be protected to not allow cross domain

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into a problem trying to get the API to do what I wanted, and really just needed JSON data including urls and captions for images for a specific account.

Use the following GET request:

https://www.instagram.com/account_name/?__a=1

where account_name is the profile I'm scraping.

It returns all JSON I needed for my task.

Comment: The '=1' at the end of the GET URL appears to be critical.  As the OP stated, without it, it just returns HTML.  With it, you get just JSON.

Comment: how can i get more thumbnail resources from this url? thanks

Comment: How do you do pagination with this approach?

Comment: This just saved my day :D How did you figure this out?!?!

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341049/1874449 for pagination of post for a given user_id. It uses a unique `query_hash` given by instagram website available in the post.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in 2022

Answer (score 17):

Update 2022:
You can no longer get the JSON output by adding the query string ?__a=1.
Currently, it would help if you used the following query string to get profile information, video, and post information on Instagram:

```
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=dis
```

[image]

Comment: where do you get those extra param &__d=dis?  it is working for me!  but from where you found about it and what does it mean? can I pass more param to restrict the search?

Comment: I tried this few times, my IP got banned next day. I tried using session with my account info and my account got banned...

Comment: It doesn't work anymore for me

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get the Json loaded in the background is too much work for a simple problem.

You should use the Instagram Api. Just put your name as a company.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, and which website do I type in as redirect url? I mean I don't own any

Comment: Here is a link to a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681090/instagram-api-redirect-url) which should help.

Comment: This is not more possible and heavily restricted

Comment: Facebook APIs were always a nightmare to work with, nowadays it's like impossible... lets scrape the hell out of them :P